# How to control custom hardware using SIMULINK

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a piece of hardware and a DLL that can be used to control it. This is essentially a motor controller that I have used from C/C++ and MATLAB. I havetried to create a SIMULINK model using the DLL and I can't seem to get it to spin the motor.

The Simulation Target is set to include the header file and DLL. The Model Properties-> callbacks include MATLAB functions to initialize the DLL and hardware. The model includes a C Caller block that should call the DLL function to set the motor speed.

When I run the simulation, I can see the initialization code being executed, the motor never starts spinning. At the end of the simulation, the cleanup function is executed.

I have two thoughts about this. First, the C Caller block doesn't support sending commands over the serial link. Second, the initialization and cleanup code are MATLAB scripts. Is it possible that the MATLAB initialization is not recognized by SDIMULINK? That is, do I have to call the DLLs init function from the model directly (I'm not sure how to do this, but a WAG would be to embed other C Callers, with the required functions).

Comment: It is possible the MATLAB calls and Simulink calls are going to different instances of the dll. You need to find a way to call init from Simulink.

Comment: That is kind of what I was thinking.  I will try to think up a way to do this and give it a try.